# Diagonalization and dimension of the eigenspaces of a matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

If a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, what does this imply involving the dimensions of the eigenspaces of $A$?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh , I know that when A is diagonalizable, then it must have n distinct eigenvalues that correspond to linearly independent eigenvectors. I do not know what this implies regarding the eigenspaces of $A$.

Comment: What is the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors and eigenspaces?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding eigenspaces. The definition given to me is that the eigenspace is the null space of $(A- \lambda I)$ which I find as somewhat unclear.

Comment: Simply put, eigenspace corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the collection of all vectors $x$ such that $Ax = \lambda x$. Clearly, if $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then it is in the eigenspace of $\lambda$ and conversely, any vector in the eigenspace is either an eigenvector or the zero vector. With this understanding, if you fix an eigenvalue, what can you say about the dimension of its eigenspace?

Comment: Thanks. I've got it now.